# MySQL server not connecting any database connections

Tags: mysql

I have tried connecting to some and all my databases in my MySQL database server but no connection are connecting either in a php script or through the MySQL console. Any guess on why this is ? I can connect fine to the MySQL database server but when it comes to selecting a database it does not connect to it. I am using 127.0.0.1 on port 80 with php MySQL and windows .

This does not connect to the database db_one or any of the others

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_one");
    if(!$con){
        die("error");
    }
    ?>
```

Also with every database I try and connect to through the command prompt

```
mysql> connect db_one
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'db_one'
```

---

Solved
by adding

```
    mysqli_select_db($con,"db_one");
```

and replacing the

```
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

seems to work

but can anyone explain this?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Isn't it obvious from the error message? Database 'db_one' doesn't exist. Are you sure you are typing the database's name correctly?

Comment: Type: create schema db_one

Comment: Yeah I guess something went wrong from installing wamp so many times . I don' t know. I am typing the correct database names. And no use on the create schema db_one

Comment: I guess this works like this . But this I procedural style am I correct ?